# How to get the size of a struct within a union in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, sizeof, unions

How do you get the size of a struct within a union in C?

Given the following definition:

```
typedef union
{
    struct req_
    {
        uint8_t cmd1;
        uint8_t cmd2;
    } req;

    struct rsp_
    {
        uint8_t cmd_result;
        uint8_t status_1;
        uint8_t status_2;
        uint8_t status_3;
        uint8_t status_4;
    } rsp;
} msg_t;
```

`sizeof(msg_t)` would provide the maximum size of the union, which in this case, would be 5 as `rsp_` is greater than `req_`.

How do you get `sizeof(req_)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
sizeof(struct req_);
```

For example:

```
int main()
{
    printf("sizeof msg_t=%zd\n",sizeof(msg_t));
    printf("sizeof struct req_=%zd\n",sizeof(struct req_));
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof msg_t=5
sizeof struct req_=2
```

Comment: Aaaah, I knew it was something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`req_` is a structure tag. You need to either put `struct` with it

```
size_t size = sizeof(struct req_);
```

or use the struct variable declared

```
size_t size = sizeof(msg_t.req_.req);
```